# How high does the ladder reach up the wall?

Tags: mathematics, geometry

A ladder of length $l$ rests against a vertical wall. Suppose that there is a rung on the ladder which has the same distance $d$ from both the wall and the (horizontal) ground. Find **explicitly**, in terms of $l$ and $d$, the height $h$ from the ground that the ladder reaches up the wall.

Comment: This is a classic maths puzzle, the ladder and box problem. It is so classic that I thought it must have been posted before, but I haven't found it.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis You are right. As I couldn't find it myself I thought it would be ok to post.

Comment: I found the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344991/the-position-of-a-ladder-leaning-against-a-wall-and-touching-a-box-under-it). I can't see why it is interesting...

Comment: @xdy Maybe more interesting if you like ladders. It's just a simply stated puzzle that is non trivial to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let h,w be the height and width of the triangle formed by the ladder with the wall and the ground.

First let us divide through with d: $H:=h/d, W:=w/d, L:=l/d, D:=d/d=1$
Then

$L^2=H^2+W^2$ (1).

Because the inscribed unit square cuts the triangle into two similar triangles using for example the top one of the two we have

> $H/W = H-1$ or $H+W = HW$ (2).

Taken together these yield a quadratic

> $L^2=(HW)^2-2HW$ (3).

with positive solution in terms of $P:=HW=H+W$

$P = 1 + \sqrt{1+L^2} (4).$

Solving for H:

$H=P-P/H$ or $H^2-HP=-P$ or $H=\frac{P \pm \sqrt{P^2-4P}}2$.

Resubstituting we finally get

$h = \frac{d + \sqrt{d^2+l^2} \pm \sqrt{l^2-2d^2-2\sqrt{d^2+l^2}}}2$

Comment: I really like how you have made the problem look almost easy to solve.

Comment: @graffe Thanks! Unlike Jaap I didn't know this problem. It's kind of neat and the little trick (2/3) satisfying to find, so thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase the problem, we wish to find the legs of a right triangle whose hypotenuse is $l$ and which contains an inscribed square of side $d$ which contains its right angle. One of these legs will be $h$ and the other will be something else - $w$ for width, say - and we can't actually tell which is which from the given information.
To begin,

> use the square to divide the triangle into two similar triangles - the legs of these are $h-d$ and $d$ and $d$ and $w-d$, respectively.
>  Scaling the former triangle by \frac{w}{d} and comparing to the original, we get that $h = \frac{hw}{d}-w$, or $w = \frac{hd}{h-d}$. Substituting this into $h^2+w^2=l^2$ and rearranging gives us a quartic in $h$ which can be solved by the usual methods.

Comment: There are clever ways to solve it that avoid the quartic, instead solving two successive quadratic equations.